# I want continues moving of image in x direction

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I want to move an image from one end to another continuously.But I have to wait till that image is going to another end. I want to continues image. Please Help me.
Here is my code

```
    ObjectAnimator objectanimator1;
    objectanimator1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img1,"x",550);
    objectanimator1.setDuration(4000);
    objectanimator1.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    objectanimator1.start();
```